# Linkedin JavaScript SDK does not always return email address of the user

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

I'm trying to integrate LinkedIn login functionality on my website using LinkedIn JavaScript SDK but It does not always return the email address of the user. Sometimes it does and sometimes it does not.

Here's my code.

**Loading the API:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
api_key:   MY_API_KEY
authorize: true
onLoad: onLinkedInLoad 
</script>
```

**This function gets called on API load:**

```
function onLinkedInLoad() {

    /*
    * Defining the scope
    */
    var scope = {scope: 'r_emailaddres'};

    /*
    * If the user is not authorized, attach a click event hander with .li-login button
    */
    if( !IN.User.isAuthorized() ) {

        $('.li-login').on('click', function( event ){
            event.preventDefault();

            IN.User.authorize(function(){
                getProfileData( false );
            }, scope);  
        });
    }
    else{

        IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", function(data){

            console.log(data)
            getProfileData( true );
        });
    } 
}
```

**getProfileData( alreadyLoggedin ) function definition:**

```
function getProfileData( alreadyLoggedin) {

    if(alreadyLoggedin){
        IN.API.Raw("/people/~:(id,firstName,lastName,emailAddress,picture-url)").result(function(response){

            $('.li-modal .user-fullname').html(response.firstName+' '+response.lastName);
            $('.li-modal img').attr('src', response.pictureUrl);
            $('.li-login').removeClass('li-login-btn'); 


            console.log(response)

        }).error(onError);
    }
    else{
        IN.API.Raw("/people/~:(id,firstName,lastName,emailAddress,picture-url)").result(function( response ){
            console.log(response);
            var data = {
                "first_name": response.firstName,
                "last_name": response.lastName,
                "email": response.emailAddress,
                "service": 'linkedin',
                "picture": response.pictureUrl,
            };  

            //attemptLogin(data); 

        }).error(onError);
    }

}
```

**Login Button code:**

```
<a href="#" class="li-login"><img src="images/linkedin-icon.png"></a>
```

**By default selected application permissions:**
[image]

A quick help will be appreciated.

Comment: I guess this depends on the privacy settings of the user.

Comment: Yes, it is. For this reason, the login process requires user consent to get permissions. I want to store the email address in the database. LinkedIn has made changes to their website otherwise, there used to be a setting where you can control the application permissions easily by checking/unchecking the checkboxes.

Comment: @Henry The strange thing is, sometimes, it returns the email address and sometimes it does not.